# How to uncommit in github for mac?

Tags: git, github-for-mac

I'm using github for mac, the GUI for git that github provides, and I reverted a commit in the history.  I then decided I wanted to revert that again, and.... long story short, I have a bunch of reverts that are unnecessary and don't want to sync that with github, but they are automatically committed so the only option I have is to sync.

Is there no way to just ignore those changes?

Comment: If you're not too scared of the command line, try `git reset <commit you want to reset to>`.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I did actually but I'm trying to see if theres a way to do this via the GUI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like there is currently no way via the GUI... Hopefully the good guys at Github will see this and take it as a feature suggestion.

For now we can only do as Tass suggested in the comment above. `git reset <commit you want to reset to>`

Answer (score 3):

Here are some of the things you can do with the GitHub for Mac GUI:

A. *Right after doing a commit in your local repo, but before syncing*, GitHub for Mac will allow you to **undo your last commit**. Use the "Undo" button at the bottom of the Changes pane. This is what I use most often.

B. After syncing, you can **revert a commit** from the GUI as follows: select your repository, then select "History". Finally select the last commit. In the detailed (file diff) view of the commit at the top you will see a "settings" gear icon. Its a drop-down menu with the entry "Revert this Commit". See below. Note that this doesn't remove your commit but it effectively undoes the changes introduced by your commit.

C. If you select an earlier commit (i.e., earlier than the last), you can use the same menu to "**Roll Back to this Commit**". Again, this doesn't removed your commits but introduces changes that have the effect of undoing them.

This is still the best that can be done via the GUI. If you actually want to remove your past commits from history, you still need to use the command line: e.g. `git rebase -i HEAD~2` will allow you to squash your last two commits into one. See [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git) for guidance.

D. Note that once you have squashed commits from the command line, you can then use (A) to reopen the last commit (i.e., the result of the squash) from the GUI.

---

[image]